# How to write a method for reducing circle radius

Tags: java, methods, geometry

I've never asked a question here before but I'm having a really tough time figuring this one out. I must be overthinking this because it seems like a simple question.

> Complete the `shrink()` method of the `Circle` class.

```
public class Circle 
    {

    private double radius;

    // constructor

    // postcondition: the instance variable is initialized

    public Circle(double rad) 
    {

    radius = rad;

    }

    // postcondition: reduces the radius of this Circle by a given percentage.

    // For example, if radius is 10.0, and percent is 20, then the new radius would be 8.0.

    public void shrink(int percent)
    {

    }

}
```

My code:

```
public void shrink(int percent) {

    radius = radius * (percent / 100);

}
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: What is the result that you are getting?  From a glance, the logic looks correct.  We need to know what you expect to get and what you are getting.

Comment: Your current formula will shrink the radius by 80% when you want to shrink it by 20%.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *shrink* by a percentage, use:

```
radius = radius * (1 - (percent / 100.0));
```

Note the `100.0`, not `100`, to prevent integer division.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are trying to divide two integers and then get a double. If you want to use the percent/100 and get a double then you would need to do

percent/100.0

which will force the typecast.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should take `public void shrink(double percent)`

```
/* document that shrink factor is expected in percentage scale (i.e .2 , .5 (half) ) etc and  have bounds from (0,1)
*/
public void shrink(double percent) {

        radius = radius * (1 - percent);

    }
```

you should have some protection and check if they pass 1 you don;t make it 0